# jQuery - how to "reset" a .css() rotated icon?

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, icons

I have an icon, which is rotated on click.

I'd like to "reset" it (without a page refresh), so it would rotate on **every** click.

```
$('#icon').click(function(){
    $(this).css('transform','rotate(360deg)');
});
```

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/tDvD9/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
var r = 0;
$('#icon').click(function(){
    $(this).css('transform','rotate(' + (r += 360) + 'deg)');
});
```

That way your "transform" property will change on each click (until somebody clicks 100 million times or so).

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very elegant solution (I think the worst part is that you have to know the transition time in the JS) but you can reset it with `setTimeout`.  The inner `setTimeout` is necessary or else it will take 3 seconds to rotate back to 0.

```
$(this).css('transform','rotate(360deg)');
setTimeout(function () {
    this.css({'transform': 'rotate(0deg)', 'transition': '0'});
    setTimeout(function () {
        this.css('transition', 'all 3s ease-in-out');
    }.bind(this), 10);
}.bind($(this)), 3000);
```

The inner `setTimeout` is done to

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/tDvD9/2/

Comment: You could add/remove a class to turn the animation on/off, perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I need it to rotate only when clicked.

Answer (score -1):

I reset it by rotate it back

```
var last=0; // rotated degree last time set to 0
var x=360;  //degree to rotate
var t=9000;  // time duration
$("#item").click(function(){ //click
  rotateme(x);// call function
});
function rotateme(x){
 if(last!=0){// if last has value
   // rotate it back
   $("#id").animate({  borderSpacing: -last }, {
       duration:0
   });
 }
 // rotate setting x,y position
 $("#id").css("transform-origin",0% 0%);
 $("#id").css("-ms-transform-origin",0% 0%);
 $("#id").css("-webkit-transform-origin",0% 0%);
 $("#id").css("-moz-transform-origin",0% 0%);
 // rotate steps
 $("#id").animate({  borderSpacing: x }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {    
    $(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)'); 
    $(this).css('-moz-transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    $(this).css('transform','rotate('+now+'deg)');
    },
    duration:t
 });
 last=x;
}
```

Comment: better to include your code directly here instead of link